# android Text View location

Tags: android, location, textview, screen

What do I need to change for the text to appear in the upper right corner of the screen?

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textSize="32sp" 
            android:text="CENTER" 
            android:editable="false" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_margin="10px"/>
```

Comment: Depends on the layout containing the text boxes. What layout are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When you want good layout control, your first choice should be a RelativeLayout:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  > 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
    android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textSize="32sp" 
        android:text="CENTER" 
        android:editable="false" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```